# GAE datastore auto built indexes doesn't contain imported data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When i was merging 2 gae instances, i took an export of the data in datastore from the first and imported it in the second.
All predefined indexes worked fine and i found the imported entities, but when i searched using auto built indexes it didn't return any values.

first time i did the import using Admin UI, then i tried using  "gcloud datastore import", yet i got the same result.

reading imported entity by key and writing it again did the refresh for that entity indexes, but if do this for all imported entities it will cost a lot $$$.
Any advice how to refresh auto built indexes as it should be automatically refreshed as mentioned in documentation.

Comment: Did the importing app's datastore composite index definitions include all the composite index definitions of the exporting app at the moment when the import was done?

Comment: Yes, all defined composite indexes are included, querying using them is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate your scenario and the indexes are building automatically. If you are still observing that built-in indexes are not automatically built after an import, you might want to file a bug at [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187197&template=1162794) so this can be further investigated.

You will be charged the same amount for your built-in indexes, irrespective of the index rebuilds being triggered manually or automatically as they will have the same reads and writes and take up the same space.